# GCC Компилятор не сравнивает строки

Tags: c++, visual-studio, gcc

Компилирую программу в VC++ и в GCC. Результаты получаются разные при сравнении строк. Вникать в суть кода необязательно: мы просто сравниваем определенные строки и если они равны высчитываем значение для двумерного вектора g. Строки формата `std::string`, но если компилятор VC++ позволяет сделать сравнение строк `==` подобным способом, то GCC - нет! Пришлось использовать преобразование `std::string` в `char*` с помощью `c_str()` и сравнивать `strcmp()`, но даже в этом случае не понятно почему GCC дает правильный результат только в половине случаев

```
vector <vector <double>> g(k, vector <double>(k, INT_MAX));
    for (int i = 0; i < k; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < v[i].neibs.size(); j++) {
            for (int p = 0; p < v.size(); p++) {
                if (strcmp(v[p].name.c_str(), v[i].neibs[j].c_str()) == 0) {
                    cout << i << " " << p << " = ";
                    g[i][p] = sqrt(pow(v[i].x - v[p].x, 2) + pow(v[i].y - v[p].y, 2));
                    cout << g[i][p] << endl;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < g.size(); i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < g[i].size(); j++)
        {
            cout << g[i][j] << " ";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
```

Comment: >позволяет сделать сравнение строк == подобным способом, то GCC - нет - вот с этого места подробнее.

Comment: Когда я прохожу по условию, то сравнения типа v[p].name == v[i].neibs[j] просто пропускается, типо строки не равны

Comment: @ego_xxx прекрасно работает сравнение строк через == в *gcc* https://rextester.com/YVB16437

Comment: Делаю на этом же сайте и не понимаю, почему подобное сравнение игнорируется. Хотя если их вывести, они будут абсолютно идентичны (строки)

Comment: Нет разницы задания строк через push_back(определенный символ) и через std::cin ? Такого что, они потом окажутся неравными

Comment: Какую-то фантастику вы сдесь расказываете. Привидети минимальный компилируемый пример вашей проблемы

Comment: подозреваю, что в одной из строк есть в конце перевод строки или что то подобное Вот оно и "не срабатывает"

Comment: @KoVadim, это не объясняет почему переход к c_str исправляет ситуацию. Разве что в строках есть '\0'.

Comment: @ego_xxx, признавайтесь как в строки могут попасть '\0'-и?

Comment: если в строке где то в середине есть нулевой символ, то как раз все хорошо объясняетт